# How do I make more space on a Macbook air?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a bunch of files that I don't need. I'm wondering what's taking up all the space. I am tempted to almost format the laptop and start fresh.

What can I do to find out what is taking up all the disk space in my Macbook?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a tool like Space Gremlin to identify files eating up your disk space. 
https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/space-gremlin/id414515628?mt=12
http://www.spacegremlinapp.com/

Answer (score -1):

Did you check your "About this Mac" and the tab "Other"?
All the files that are not in one of the listed categories.

This [article](http://www.theminidrive.com/blogs/theminiblog/116219845-other-storage-space-the-big-monster-of-mac-os-x) talks about what is other and how to clean your mac safely